# my all categories convert to NaN or 'missing' ; what's the problem?

Tags: machine-learning, pandas, preprocessing

###### Hello, I have a dataFrame and one of features is categorical and I want to convert that to ordinal category(including a category for missing values)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

###### but in the last cell as you see it assumes all of my categories as NaN (-1) and even I use X.fillna('missing') assumes all of those as 'missing'

###### I don't no what's the problem and I couldn't find any helpful documentation.

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at what `pandas.Categorical` returns and saved in the `cat` variable, they are all `NaN` values. This is because you are setting the categories to a list of strings, whereas the values in the `edu_level` column are values, meaning that the string values do not occur in the column and the values are therefore set to missing.

Comment: Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned two issues in the code :

1. issue 1 : Our missing value is encoded as a seperate class

It is no longer a missing value , as you put np.NAN there and nan will considered as a seperate class in the Ordinal Encoder

2. order is not respected becuse the categories are not specified, so it will take as auto and the most occured value will treated as first .

As @Oxbowerce commented , your pandas.Categorical will return -1 for all since the values are present instead of string .

in your code , I am not sure why you are substituing np.NAN() .

```
X = pd.DataFrame ( np.array ( [ 'M', 'O-', 'medium',
                                 'M', 'O-', 'high', 
                               'F', 'O+', 'high', 
                               'F', 'AB', 'low', 
                               'F', 'B+', np.NAN]).reshape((5,3)))
X.columns = ['sex', 'blood_type', 'edu_level']
```

at this point , if you know this is missing value, it is better to substitute here itself rather than complicating

or after your processing , if you want to convert back to categories including your missing value, you can simply do by

```
edu_dict = {2.0: 'Low', 0.0: 'High', 1.0: 'Medium',  3.0: 'Missing', }
X['edu_level'] = X['edu_level'].map(edu_dict)
```

output :

```
  sex blood_type edu_level
0   M         O-       Low
1   M         O-      High
2   F         O+      High
3   F         AB    Medium
4   F         B+   Missing
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir , I get it